# Fullcalendar remove vertical lines

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using full calendar **3.9.0** version to create a nice and beautiful calendar. After adding this piece of code

```
slotDuration: {
      'hours': 12
    },
```

a day column is divided and I can see a vertical line in a specific day for example Fri 5.

[image]

According to the functionality, this is what I want but not from the design perspective. How do I remove it and make it look something like this?

[image]

This is what it looked like before adding **slotDuration** property in configuration options.

I checked the [slotRender hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slot-render-hooks) from the docs and cannot find the solution.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Slot render hooks don't apply to your version. You need to look at the documentation for v3 not v5. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc

Comment: Anyway you can probably get rid of the grid lines by tweaking the CSS. Have you tried to inspect what rule puts those lines onto the page? Have you tried to change any code? But also consider whether your changes might make the calendar less usable as well as (in your opinion) better looking. The lines exist for a reason.

Comment: Yes @ADyson I did. I tried to look into the css by inspecting but I thought it would be better if we have some similar functionality from library per se and then the question.